# Blank page after running Cypress tests

Tags: cypress

Whenever I run a new cypress test, the page that is supposed to show the UI is blank. Even when I click on each part of each test it remains blank. Please see image below.

image

[image: 1]

Cypress package version: 10.4.0 
Node v16.16.0

Code:

```
    describe("home page", () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000")
    })

    context("Hero section", () => {
      it("the h1 contains the correct text", () => {
      cy.getByData("hero-heading").contains(
        "Testing Next.js Applications with Cypress"
      )
    })

    it("the features on the homepage are correct", () => {
      cy.get("dt").eq(0).contains("4 Courses")
      cy.get("dt").eq(1).contains("25+ Lessons")
      cy.get("dt").eq(2).contains("Free and Open Source")
    })
  })

  context("Courses section", () => {
    it("CourseL Testing Your First Next.js Application", () => {
      cy.getByData('course-0')
        .find('a')
        .eq(3)
        .contains('Get started')
    })
  })
})

    /// <reference types="cypress" />

    Cypress.Commands.add('getByData', (selector) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-test=${selector}]`);
});
```

Answer (score 45):

I faced the same issue in Cypress version 12.0.0 and I solved it by adding this configuration to cypress.config.js

```js
testIsolation: false,
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmed. This issue was driving crazy!

Comment: I'm Glad it helped. I hope they make it more obvious in the docs

Comment: Documentation: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation

Comment: As per the docs, is it not a bad practice to turn off the testIsolation flag? It says that it can make the test flaky.

Comment: But doesn't "make test flaky" is a bad practice :D 
IMHO it's nice that test isolation is the default so that you program your mind to do it.

Comment: It probably will make it flaky if you're not careful about how you clean up after your tests... however I prefer the speed over the risk of flakiness. You can always write a test in isolation in it's own test fixture to guarantee isolation...

Comment: Thanks for this, I just upgraded a project to version 13 from 11. I was wondering why it was clearing local storage, session storage and cookies in all domains. It is enabled by default. Just set it to false within e2e configuration then re-open Cypress UI.

Answer (score 5):

In your cypress.config.js page, make the below changes to include testIsolation :

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
   setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
    // implement node event listeners here
    },
    testIsolation: false,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have put the `it()` `describe()` statements in the wrong place. Try creating the most simple test file possible or better still use an example test that cypress provides strip it down and continue to test it until it is barebones.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding 's' to http; this might solve that else here is similar issue reported which might give you clue to your problem https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4235

Answer (score -4):

I have a "solution" in my tests - it seems that the `it` steps lose the URL.

Remove all the `it` steps:

```js
describe('Register Native', () => {
  // it("Verify1", () => {
   : a
  // })
  // it("Verify2", () => {
   : b
  // })
})
```

Now I have a structure like this (only one `it` step):

```js
describe('Registrer Native', () => {
  it('Whole test- Without IT parts', () => {
: a
: b
: c
  })
})
```

It is not an optimal solution as I now have a long test without intermediary `it` sections.